# Distribute nodes on the same rank of a wide graph to different lines

Tags: nodes, graphviz, dot

I have a graph (organigram) how this:

```
digraph G {
nodesep=0.3;
ranksep=0.2;
margin=0.1;
node [shape=rectangle];
edge [arrowsize=0.8];
1 -> 2;
1 -> 3;
1 -> 4;
1 -> 5;
1 -> 6;
1 -> 7;
1 -> 8;
1 -> 9;
1 -> 10;
}
```

[image]

I have organigrams with 70 people and it's impossible to print in A4. How would I put nodes in 2 or 3 lines?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here are two possibilities (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6436178/63733)):

### 1. Use the `unflatten` utility

Graphviz provides a tool called [`unflatten`](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/unflatten.1.pdf). If you pre-process your graph using this command line:

```
unflatten -l 3 wide.gv | dot -Tpng -o wide.png
```

the output image will be similar to the below picture. This is slightly less wide, and you may play with the `-l` option.

[image: graphviz unflattened graph example]

### 2. Use `rank=same' and invisible edges

You may use the standard techniques to make a automatically layed out graphs look more like you want it to:

- `rank=same` to group nodes in *subgraphs* and to define which nodes should be on the same line
- invisible edges to ensure that the different subgraphs appear on different ranks
- maybe some `constraint=false` for some edges to influence the layout
- `group` attributes of nodes to encourage straight edges.

The output graph will not necessarily be prettier...

Here's an example, you can probably do better. Also, this may not be very practical if the graph is generated dynamically.

```
digraph G {
nodesep=0.3;
ranksep=0.2;
margin=0.1;
node [shape=rectangle];
edge [arrowsize=0.8];


edge[style=invis];
node[group=a];
2->5->8;
node[group=b];
1->3->6->9;
node[group=c];
4->7->10;


edge[style=solid];
1 -> 2;
1 -> 3;
1 -> 4;
edge[constraint=false];
1 -> 5;
1 -> 6;
1 -> 7;
1 -> 8;
1 -> 9;
1 -> 10;
}
```

[image: graphviz output]

Comment: `unflatten` doesn't support Unicode characters. But that's because you use PowerShell! If you use Bash it works fine. See [the differences between the output here](https://forum.graphviz.org/t/is-it-possible-to-make-the-rank-shuffle-without-using-invisible-edges/1024/6?u=ooker)