# Make Graph in GraphViz use the full screen height

Tags: graphviz

To debug a Tic Tac Toe AI I wrote, I need to visualize the tree of the game it builds for the mini max algorithm.
To do this, I use jgrapht and its GraphMLExporter. It generates me a file that I can open with GraphViz.

As Tic Tac Toe has many turn combinations, the tree is very wide but has a low height. This squeezes it and when I zoom in in the png output, I can only see pixels.

So here is my question:
How can I make GraphViz use the full screen height? It does not matter to me how wide the graph is, I just want to set something like a minimum height.
Thanks for helping,
vat

Comment: Can you share the file and the command you are using? Otherwise it's pure speculation.

Comment: Please take a look an my [answer using the unflatten utility](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11136488/63733) to break down wide graphs. That's the graphviz tool to handle this problem. If this doesn't apply to your problem, tell me why not and I may reopen the question.

Comment: @vaettchen: Since I did not find a possibility right now to upload it directly, I put it into my dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqynt6yqqyrwt4g/gameTreeAsVisioFile.dot?dl=0

Comment: Actually, I do appreciate it, that all nodes of equal level are next to each other, I just want to scale the graph up so that it uses the entire screen height.

Comment: And so far, I used the GUI of GraphViz and I opened the file and tried it with different settings including...

graph[fontsize="12"]
graph[dpi="8000"]
node[fontsize="12"]
edge[fontsize="12"]
graph[defaultdist="80"]
edge[penwidth="5"]

I also experimented with size and the exclamation mark ! but it did not do the trick.

Comment: Keeping nodes of equal level next to each other, but scale the graph up to use the entire screen height - this would result in nodes with a small width but a very high height, correct?

Comment: Yep, but width does not matter to me,. it can be as wide as it wants to

Comment: While I could not yet fix the prob in my TicTacToe AI, I found a solution to my graph problem. I can open the GraphML with a software called yEd (its free). It has very useful layout algorithms and I managed to visualize the tree in it.