# How to arrange nodes better

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphviz

I draw my nodes via Graphviz, but the layout is too horizontal. I am using the `dot` engine, but also the other engines don't really provide a nice layout. The root node `xyz` has edges to all 2-blocks `bar` and `bas`, but it would look much nicer if they are stacked vertically. Could you give me a hint how to improve that?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11134946/63733 Would this resolve your problem ?