# Edges output by graphviz dot bunch up

Tags: graphviz

How can I prevent the lines bunching up and making up unclear what leads to what, as shown in this image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple way would be to **increase [`ranksep`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:ranksep)** - the minimal distance between two ranks. This should leave more space for the edges, at least if you're using dot.

If the concentration of edges is due to a lot of nodes on the same rank, you may consider using the **[`unflatten`](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/unflatten.1.pdf) utility**. Including this step in the generation of the graph allows to distribute nodes on the same rank to different ranks and therefore make the graph narrower (but longer), creating some space between the nodes. The edges to the individual nodes should then be more easily distinguishable.
A complete example on how to use the unflatten utility (with picture) can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11136488/63733).