# Graphviz DOT file distorted rendering (terraform graph)

Tags: graph, terraform, graphviz, dot, distortion

I'm new to Graphviz and I'm getting a distorted image of my DOT file generated from `terraform graph` command which I'm trying to either lighten or increase the height of elements because they are really thin compared to their width.

To give you an example of the problem I'm facing (this is a really big schema):
[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73262051/how-can-i-adjust-a-graphviz-render

Comment: @sroush Found a solution and posted it below

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to `terraform graph` which outputs everything on the same subgraph/rank.

Someone did a beautifier to solve this: https://github.com/pcasteran/terraform-graph-beautifier