# GraphViz: Compress automatically generated graph

Tags: graphviz

I am trying to visualize two columns of an an Excel file: Column A contains categories, while Column B contains individual entries. The dot file is generated by Excel using the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(CONCATENATE("subgraph cluster_",A2,"{""",B2,"""","; label =""",A2,"""}"),"")
```

Afterwards the "unflatten" utility is used to distribute the nodes more evenly, and finally the "dot" is used to generate the graph

```
unflatten.exe -f -l 4 -c 6 -o FLATTENED.dot INPUTFILE.dot
dot -Tpng FLATTENED.dot > FLATTENED.png
```

The [following graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5cSo.jpg) is generated

I would like to make the graph more compact, and align the categories to the upper egde of the page, what commands should I look into to improve the resulting output?

I've attached the [dot file](http://pastebin.com/JZw1zgH1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an idea:

- Instead of one graph with x clusters create a dot file with x graphs
- unflatten them
- then use [`gvpack`](https://graphviz.org/pdf/gvpack.1.pdf) to pack all graphs together
- and neato to layout

The basic idea is to use graphs instead of clusters so you can use `gvpack` to pack the graphs.

Something like:

```
unflatten -f -l 4 -c 6 input.dot | dot | gvpack -array_t6 | neato -s -n2 -Tpng -o output.png
```

Not sure though whether unflatten handles files with several graphs.

(Sorry, no time to check it).

Comment: Thanks, your approach was very useful for my problem.

Comment: where can I find the documentation for `gvpack`?

Comment: @Ooker I've added a link to the documentation