# how to layout child nodes in graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot, graph-layout

Here's my dot code:
I have 3 levels of nodes. Currently, In the 3rd level (bottom), I have one row of child node (orange colour), but the bottom level is too long. I would like to have two rows of child nodes .

Please suggest me how to get two rows of child nodes.

```
digraph {
overlap=false
rankdir=BT
root="node0"
node [fillcolor="#ffcc99",shape=box, fontname="Tahoma",style=filled]
edge [length=100, color=black, fontColor=black]
node0 [ fillcolor=cyan, label="TOPOLO"]
node1 [ fillcolor=yellow, label="MY Mobile-USSP-Topup"]
node1 -> node0
node2 [ label="MY PMP Router" ]
node2 -> node1
node3 [ label="MY USSP" ]
node3 -> node1
node4 [ label="MY PMP Airgate" ]
node4 -> node1
node5 [ label="MY LB P2C" ]
node5 -> node1
node6 [ label="MY WLS-PB" ]
node6 -> node1
node7 [ label="MY CPB" ]
node7 -> node1
node8 [ label="MY P2C/RTU" ]
node8 -> node1
node9 [ label="MY LB" ]
node9 -> node1
node10 [ label="MY CCP OCU WS" ]
node10 -> node1
node11 [ label="MY CCP OCU OCS" ]
node11 -> node1
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I optimize GraphViz output width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402535/how-can-i-optimize-graphviz-output-width)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/11891175/63733 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17157811/63733 for `unflatten` examples